# Start/Stop program from php on windows

Tags: php, windows, service, server

I running a minecraft server on a windows machine.
Now I want to run multiple other servers too on the same machine. (not minecraft)

We are only few people, so they are not playing every day.

I want to create a small webpage with a button for each game-server, so that they can start the server for the game they want to play.
Also there should be a button for stopping a server.

There are multiple tutorials for start/stop windows services from php.
Also there are tutorials and tools for creating services that run batch files. Starting the game-servers seems to be no problem.

But, e.g. if I stop the minecraft server, I want to write a message to the chat, then call the save-world command and then call the stop command. All this have to be done in the command line window.

I found a tutorial for doing this in linux but how can I do this for windows?

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: `exec`, `shell_exec` and the backtick operator work in windows too, you can execute programs easily

Comment: shell_exec is good to start the server. But if I want to shutdown, I have to pass the command to the same command line window. How to do this with shell_exec?